# C++ generic class design with methods which return subclass

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing a generalized list for Unicode code-point. The problem is I also want some general class design which allowing specialized version. Here's the example.

This is an example.

```
class
MyString
{
public:
    auto getItemAt(int index) const -> UnicodePoint const;
    auto subsetInRange(int index, int length) const -> MyString const;
    auto getUTF8Binary() const -> std::string const;
};
```

Here's only one, but actually, there're bunch of methods like `subsetInRange`, so I don't want to repeat to write them for other data types. That leads me to write a generic version superclass.

```
template<typename T, typename FINAL_SELF_TYPE>
class
MyList
{
public:
    auto getItemAt(int index) const -> T const;
    auto subsetInRange(int index, int length) const -> FINAL_SELF_TYPE const;
    // getUTF8Binary() removed because it's inappropriate on this abstraction level.
};

class
MyString : public MyList<UnicodePoint, MyString>
{
public:
    auto getUTF8Binary() const -> std::string const;
};
```

Finally I had to admit I have to pass final class type as a template parameter to `MyList` class to make it work properly. And it feels something wrong. I can't say what it is exactly, but my brains keep sending warning signal. I think it's because I am putting some specialization information on abstracted general class. Which seems circular dependency - not good at any case. It's fully against to class hierarchy.

But when I write some general classes has methods return same type as a result, I always see this pattern. It's bugging me. Due my short C++ experience, I cannot have some confidence on my design.

How is this pattern to you? Good or wrong? If it's wrong, what's wrong?

Comment: Seems like some good old CRTP if you ask me, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @j_kubik I would choose your comment as the answer if you wrote it as an answer. That CRTP stuff finally made my brain sending warning signal.

Comment: Seems too short for an answer, but if you like...

Comment: @j_kubik I don't think answer need to be long to be good. Please convert it to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read more about [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). It is actually quite common design pattern.